# Using routeProvider when not on site root

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-routing

Sorry if I'm missing something obvious, very new to Angular.

I'm running an application on this page: //hosted.demo.ca/md/SitePages/Home.aspx
I'm trying to set up the routing on the application but the page is just rendering blank with no errors in console.

routeProvider:

```
var spApp = angular.module('spApp', [])
    .config(function($routeProvider){
        $routeProvider.when('/userView', 
        {
            templateUrl: 'partials/userView.html', 
            controller: 'userCtrl'
        })
    });
```

and my html like such:

```
<div id="mdContainer" ng-cloak>
        <!-- Navigation --> 
        <div id='mdSidebar'>
            <ul>
               <li id="menuHome"><a href='#'><span>Home</span></a></li>
               <li id="menuUsers"><a href='#/userView'><span>Users</span></a></li>
               <li id="menuGroups"><a href='#'><span>Groups</span></a></li>
               <li id="menuSites"><a href='#'><span>Sites</span></a></li>
               <li id="menuReports"><a href='#'><span>Reports</span></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <!-- Main view --> 
        <ng-view></ng-view>
    </div>
```

Comment: because your location does not match `/userView` which is what you have your route set to.

Comment: But the user view should be called when the user button is click, however, the container doesn't load at all.

Comment: remove the # from the link, i believe angular hooks all links inside the ngapp container, so i do not believe you need the # in front.

Comment: I removed the # but that didn't do anything. It has something to do with ngCloak. Should I remove it from the container and put it in the partials?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you added the route module?  Please try using something like:

```
var spApp = angular.module('spApp', ['ngRoute'])
```

See [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute) for more information about this.  In newer versions of Angular the route functions were moved to a separate module.

Also I can tell you from personal experience that it is very easy to forget to add the angular-route.js file into your html file using something like:

```
<script src="path/to/angular-route.js">
```

If you use bower you can easily set this up with:

```
bower install angular-route
```

Comment: Oh I see. Yea because I'm watching a pluralsight tutorial and they aren't doing that. I'll try doing this and see if that works. Thanks.

Comment: @Batman, which version you using? the older ones work the way you have it since the route provider was compiled in with the rest of angular.

Comment: then yea you need to do as snapshot says add in the ngroute js file and change the code to add in the ngRoute to the call.

Comment: Regarding your comment about forgetting, thanks for the heads up. I'm using LABs script loader so it makes it easier to add these files

Comment: crazy there's no console error for this. I would never had known.